# Redux-form validation based on field in other form

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have 2 forms, in which the validation for a field in the second form is based on the value of a field in the first form. This works as expected when filling in the form top-down. However, when I change the value in the first form, the `values` object isn't updated in the validation.

My validate-function looks something like this:

```
const validate = values => {
  const errors = {}
  if (!values.username) {
    errors.username = 'Required'
  } else if (values.username.length < values.previous_field.length) {
    errors.username = 'Your name can't be shorter than the previous field';
  }

  return errors;
}
```

When I change the previous field to a short value after filling in a valid username, the username-field never invalidates.

Comment: Try to `handleSubmit(noop)` second form after `previous_field` of the first one was changed.

Comment: if no answer here then you can search or create issue in redux-form github page https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues

Comment: @elmeister You mean to re-submit the first form when the second value is changed?

Comment: @RajabShakirov, the issues are meant for bugs, not for usage related questions.

Comment: @ashwin-van-dijk no, resubmit second form to call `validate` on `username ` again, when `previous_field ` of the first form was changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to rename the forms so then would both have the same name. In this way the values do get updated, and you can use the validation in the way I would like.

Both forms are now named `userdata`, and the first one has all the validation logic:

```
@reduxForm({
  form: 'userdata',
  validate,
  asyncValidate,
  asyncBlurFields: ['car_licenceplate', 'user_zipcode']
})
```